# Applying the integral test for the series $\sum _{n =1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \ln n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Applying the integral test for the series $\sum _{n =1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \ln n}$, I am wondering what will I do when $n = 1$ I think I will get an improper integral in both the integrand and the upper limit of the integration, then what shall I do, could anyone tell methe details of this please?

Comment: Start the sum at $n=2$.

Comment: so the first term does not matter with me .... correct?@ChinnapparajR

Comment: The sum itself is not defined for the $n=1$ term. If this was presented in some textbook, it is probably just an oversight, and you should consider the sum starting at $n=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general term is not defined for $n=1$, so that the sum as is presented is not defined. However, it is well defined if you start at $n=2$.

Anyway, if you had any other problem when applying some test for
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n$$
(for instance, if you had to compute $\int_2^\infty f(x) dx$ for some $f$ with discontinuities in the interval $(2,\infty)$, or if some necessary hypothesis only were valid from some point on), remember that this series will converge if and only if
$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n,$$
for any $k\ge 2$. This means you can always choose to omit an initial interval as needed.

For instance, you can't apply the integral test to the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{|n^3-2|}}$$
by computing
$$\int_0^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{|x^3-2|}}dx$$
(give it a thought to this, there might be more than one reason),
but you can apply the test to 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{|n^3-2|}}$$
by computing
$$\int_2^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{|x^3-2|}}dx,$$
and using the fact that both series will converge or both won't (in this case, they're both well defined).